# Sorting an array without losing the original index in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm working on a function that gets an array and sort it without losing the original indexes, for example:

```
    originalArray[5] = {9, 2, 3, 4, 15};
    // code
    // ..
```

result:

```
sortedArr[5] = {2, 3, 4, 9, 15};
index[5] = {1, 2, 3, 0, 4};
```

notice how

```
/*
index[0] == 1 because sortedArr[0] == originalArr[1]
index[3] == 0 because sortedArr[3] == originalArr[0]
index[4] == 4 because sortedArr[4] == originalArr[4]
*/
```

and so on the point is saving the indexes of the numbers so I can use them in another function. in the example I made two array (sorted and original) it should be the same array I made those just to explain my point. the Time complexity should is limited to O(n*log(n)). n represents the size of the array, (the maximum is 100).

its recommended (the teacher recommended it for us) to use a function of the signature

```
void rem_sort(int array[], int index[], int size)
```

.
EDIT: so everyone have been asking me what have I tried so far, if that helps you to assist me, I'm sorry I didn't mention it first, anyway this is what I tried so far, first I tried to sort the array I succeeded but I lost the indexes of the original array and that's not my point, so I thought if I make a new "temp" array and copy my original array to it and sort it this way I wont affect my original array but I cant get the indexes right (with this complexity), I thought about using pointers but I don't know how should I do it so I'm stuck!

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Use a `struct` array that holds the data and the original index. When sorted, the original index is still known.

Comment: Initialize the `index` array with numbers 0..n, use a `mergesort` or `qsort` on on this array with a sort function that compares indirectly through the `index` array, make a final pass storing the sorted values into `sortedArr`.

Comment: Okay, so what have you done so far?

Comment: @immibis first I tried to sort the array, well its not a problem to sort it but I lost the indexes and that's not my point, I tried something else, making a temp array sorting it so I wont affect the original one but I also couldn't get the indexes so now I'm kinda of stuck (I know its nothing to most of u but I just started)

Comment: In your question, you should show what you tried, and describe why what you tried didn't work, or what about what you tried confused you.

Comment: @jxh I edited my question you can check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is C and not C++, you'll need to create your own sort program since I think qsort() can be O(n^2) worst case.

Since you will be using your own sort program, you could just sort the array and the indices at the same time, treating them as pairs of elements.

If there was an existing O(n log(n)) sort function that you could call, you could create an array of indices 0 to length-1, and sort the array of indices according to the array, then copy the array to a temp array according to the sorted indices, then copy the temp array back to the original array.

```
void rem_sort(int array[], int index[], int size){
    /* temp array */
    int * tmpa = malloc(size * sizeof(array[0]));
    int i;
    /* generate indices to array */
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        index[i] = i;
    /* sort index according to array in O(n log(n)) time */
    sort(array, index, size);
    /* tmpa[] = sorted array[] */
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tmpa[i] = array[index[i]];
    /* copy tmpa to array */
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = tmpa[i];
    free(tmpa);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `mergesort` has `N.log(N)` complexity, but requires N extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's simple and self explanatory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct array_struct
{
    int value;
    int index;
};

int
compare_array_elements(const void *const x, const void *const y)
{
    const struct array_struct *sx;
    const struct array_struct *sy;

    sx = x;
    sy = y;

    return sx->value - sy->value;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct array_struct array[5] = {{9, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}};
    size_t size;
    size_t count;

    size = sizeof(array[0]);
    count = sizeof(array) / size;

    qsort(array, count, size, compare_array_elements);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
        fprintf(stdout, "(%d, %d, %d)\n", i, array[i].value, array[i].index);
    return 0;
}
```