# Ordering array values while tracking their original position

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

I want to keep track of the original position of the values after sorting them.

I saw a solution to this a while back but I lost it somewhere, it was done using a multi-set and pairs.

```cpp
int x[2][2] = { {3, 2}, {1, 4}};

sorted_x = { {4,(1,1)}, {3,(0,0)}, {2,(0,1)}, {1,(1,0)} };
```

I have been trying for a few hours now and am unable to find it.

Comment: `int x[]` is a 1d array

Comment: [keeping track of the original indices of an array after sorting in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586499/keeping-track-of-the-original-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting-in-c)

Comment: [Sort and keep track of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248149/sort-and-keep-track-of-elements)

Comment: [C++ sorting and keeping track of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577475/c-sorting-and-keeping-track-of-indexes)

Comment: [Sorting an array without losing the original index in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864228/sorting-an-array-without-losing-the-original-index-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can populate some container that contains the elements together with their index and then sort that:

```
struct element_and_index {
     int value;
     size_t x;
     size_t y;
     bool operator<(const element_and_index& other) const {
         return value < other.value;
     }
};

std::vector<element_and_index> temp;

// ... populate the vector ....

std::sort(temp.begin(),temp.end());
```

Comment: The operator signature should have `const` after it for full utility, so `bool operator<(const element_and_index& other) const {`. For instance, if you used this in `std::priority_queue<>`, it wouldn't work.